# Get details on an EXE file signature with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, code-signing, digital-certificate

I'm trying to retrieve the details on an executable file's digital signature in a managed code. I basically need the name and the issuer off the cert. There's a [C++ code sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323809/en-us) from Microsoft that explains it for C++, but is there a similar way of doing it with C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a crypto object from the signed file, using this function :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromsignedfile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Then call the .Issuer property on that object.

Comment: Thanks. I get a value in a form of FQDN as such: `"CN=Subject Name, OU=Company, O=Subject Name, STREET=Main St., STREET=39C, L=City, S=WA, PostalCode=98001, C=US"` Is there any way to parse it?

Comment: Not from the object in a strongly typed way, but you could do something like var values = string.Split(",");

Comment: Yeah. I posted a separate question on the subject. But thanks anyway. It's way more easy to achieve in a managed code :)

Comment: @DavidC: Don't simply split on commas. The company name may include a comma as well.

Comment: @ThomasW. Good point, in a production environment utility that could be ran on any random certificate, you'd want a to write your own parsing function that dissected the string based on the keys.